# ObjectInputStream.readobject() throws object in exception

Tags: java, binaryfiles, objectinputstream

When i run the code below, the objIn.readObject(); throws a exception:

> classNotFoundException project.Edge

The project.Edge is the object who i try to read from the file.

```
Object o = null;
ObjectInputStream objIn = null;
try {
    objIn = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("objects.dat"));
    o = objIn.readObject();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
while (o != null) {
   //do stuff
}
```

Comment: The exception isn't strange, you should just call `ex.printStackTrace()` rather than `System.out.println(ex.getMessage());` to see what it is.

Comment: `readObject()` only loads the data of a class, not the class itself. Therefore  all classes used or referenced in `objects.dat` must be available in your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have this problem, check if the project.Edge is in the same package as when  you write the binary file.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your `project.Edge` class not compiled correctly. Also check your classpath, this class must be available in your project.